# Censored internet on terminal

Tags: command-line, internet, proxy, tor

In office I have a limitation on internet due to Fortinet. I can access to website by using Tor browser but not enable to download and make updates through terminal.

Is there anyway to bypass the guard for terminal?

Comment: Tor essentially sets up a SOCKS proxy, but apt doesn't support SOCKS proxies. Look into something like redsocks which will work as a HTTP proxy and forward connections to Tor's SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Check your company's policy on outside Internet access - You _could_ get fired.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify) described how to use `torify` for terminal

> `torify` is a simple wrapper that attempts to find the best underlying
>   Tor wrapper available on a system. It calls `torsocks` or `tsocks`
>   with a tor specific configuration file.
>
> As first thing install the software, tor is usually found on all the
>   repository so for Debian, Ubuntu and Mint you just have to type:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install tor
> ```
>
> In this example we’ll keep all the standard configuration but 2
>   things, in the file `/etc/tor/torrc` you should uncomment the
>   directive:
>
> ```
> ControlPort 9051
> ```
>
> And set
>
> ```
> CookieAuthentication 0
> ```
>
> With these 2 options we set the port on which Tor will listen for
>   local connections from Tor controller applications, and we tell to Tor
>   that we don’t need an authentication, so any program can control Tor
>   (don’t do this on a shared computer or server), later in this post
>   I’ll show how to set a password, once changed save the file and
>   restart tor with the command:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart
> ```
>
> And now a simple example that shows how to use the command `torify`
>   and start a new session on tor from the Linux terminal, as first thing
>   I get my public IP address with:
>
> ```
> $  curl ifconfig.me
> 79.35.56.153
> ```
>
> So 79.35.56.153 is my public IP, now I use `torify` before the command
>   curl in the command line :
>
> ```
> $ torify curl ifconfig.me 2&gt;/dev/null
> 74.120.15.150
> ```
>
> As you can see now I browse on the net with a different Ip:
>   74.120.15.150, but from the command line I can also force Tor to start a “new session” with the command:
>
> ```
> echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE ""\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
> 250 OK
> 250 OK
> 250 closing connection
> ```
>
> This small script connects to port 9051 and issue the command “signal
>   newnym” that will make Tor switch to clean circuits, so new
>   application requests don’t share any circuits with old ones, now if I
>   check my IP I expect to see a new one:
>
> ```
> $ torify curl ifconfig.me 2&gt;/dev/null
> 46.59.74.15
> ```
>
> In this small example I’ve used curl to get my ip address, but with
>   `torify` you could use almost any terminal program, such as `ssh,
>   wget, w3m or BitchX`.
>
> **How to set a password for Tor**
>
> If you are in a shared environment it’s better to set up a password
>   for Tor, here it’s how you can do it in a few steps:
>
> 1. Generating your encrypted password:
>
> In a terminal type:
>
> ```
> tor --hash-password "passwordhere"
> ```
>
> This will generate a password hash, you will need to save this for
>   inserting into the TOR configuration file in the next step. (This is
>   the hash for “passwordhere”,
>   16:113BD60B17CD1E98609013B4426860D576F7096C189184808AFF551F65)
>
> 2. Editing the Tor configuration file :
>
> Open the file `/etc/tor/torrc` and comment the line we set before:
>
> ```
> #CookieAuthentication 0
> ```
>
> Next find the line:
>
> ```
> #HashedControlPassword 16:2283409283049820409238409284028340238409238
> ```
>
> remove the # at the beginning and replace the password hash that is
>   currently there with the hash you have just generated.
>
> So with the hash generated in this example the configuration would be:
>
> ```
> HashedControlPassword 16:113BD60B17CD1E98609013B4426860D576F7096C189184808AFF551F65
> ```
>
> Save your changes.
>
> 3. Restart TOR:
>
> Restart Tor so it get the new directives with:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart
> ```
>
> Now you can use the former command to connect to teh Tor daemon, but
>   using your password, so for me this would be:
>
> ```
> echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE "passwordhere"\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
> ```
>
> References:
>
> - [data-scraping-series-2-1-rotating-your-tor-ip-address-php-or-linux](http://fixitts.com/2012/09/28/data-scraping-series-2-1-rotating-your-tor-ip-address-php-or-linux/)
> - [Using Tor to Anonymize Your Traffic (and setting up Tor in Arch Linux)](http://www.speakingcode.com/2012/04/13/using-tor-to-anonymize-your-traffic/)
> - [Using Tor in Ubuntu | Torify our life](http://vocf.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/using-tor-in-ubuntu-torify-our-life/)

Comment: >sudo apt-get install tor
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
--
Also
/etc/tor/torrc no tor folder at that direction